# Least CPU intensive way of streaming your screen on windows?

Tags: windows, video, streaming, screen-capture

sometimes I like capturing my screen for others to see. Only thing: I am playing games while I do it.

I have tried a few streaming solutions where Windows Media Encoder coupled with my own Windows server appealed to me most, because I can change resolutions, etc.

I also tried ustream coupled with the Flash applet and the Adobe Flash Encoder recording a Camtasia source. Camtasia has the disadvantage though that it shows the green-and-black-alternating borders and can not be targeted fullscreen.

I like how xfire does it. But it doesn't work with every game, many are simply not supported.

A few thoughts about this:

- Is there a program which captures like Fraps or XFire (based on Direct3D and OpenGL outputs) and exposes the output to a DirectShow source filter?
- Which brings me to: Is there hardware accelerated capturing directly from the graphics card? Maybe including direct encoding with help from OpenCL? Modern graphic cards decode BluRay content directly for example. I should have a modern enough graphics processor for this to be possible (see below).
- If using Windows Media Encoder: Which are the least CPU intensive settings? Which codec?
- Is there a newer codec than Windows Media 9? Is it less CPU intensive? I only have 7, 8 and 9 inside the Encoder
- Could the performance be massively increased by having a Quad-Core CPU (see below)?

Bandwidth is no problem up to 1000 to 1500 kbit/s (I have 2048).

My Computer specs:

- Intel Core 2 Duo E8400
- 4 GB DDR2-800 Ram
- Ati Radeon HD5770
- Using Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try www.livestream.com's procaster . Xfire uses their technology.

Comment: Very interesting. It also hooks directly into the game! (Which SHOULD be more CPU effective..?)

XFire went out for me (it doesn't start anymore), but that's another story.

I'd love being able to use this livestream software or something very similar with my own server, so I can set my own quality and kbit/s used ;). 

There's got to be something like this.

Anyway, thanks a lot. There's still room for other answers though ;)